# cherrypy dynamically add objects

Tags: python, cherrypy

I'm using cherrypy to mimic an existing RESTful interface.  One requirement is that I have is to be able to add objects on the fly.

So, for example, let's say I have an object, called myobj.  I want to be able to expose a method that is based on an object added by the user. So, I would have an "add" context, where I create the object

```
http://example.ex/myobj+create
```

and I would be able to retrieve the object that's created, as well as any children:

```
http://example.ex/myobjs/obj1
http://example.ex/myobjs/obj1/child1
```

Is this possible with cherrypy?  Should I be investigating a different framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can add handlers dynamically. Just execute `obj1.child1 = Child(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look at the [_cp_dispatch](https://bitbucket.org/cherrypy/cherrypy/src/b0c48210b250/cherrypy/test/test_dynamicobjectmapping.py) or [popargs](https://bitbucket.org/cherrypy/cherrypy/src/b0c48210b250/cherrypy/__init__.py#cl-366) facilities that CherryPy 3.2+ offers. They are less known and unfortunately I couldn't find proper doc for them but they would do what you're after. Alternatively, you could use the Routes or selector dispatchers.

Answer (score 0):

[CherryPy 3.2 (REST)](http://docs.cherrypy.org/dev/progguide/REST.html) provides an interface for creating RESTful interfaces.

Comment: Yes, but from what I can tell, cherrypy exposes only those resources that are defined at app-start.  So, if I have a class that's defined in code, (as with the Resource class in the doc you link to) I can get and set parameters on it.

What I'm looking for is more dynamic:  the name of a class is defined by the user, and the URL is constructed to link to the created class.